# Bell's inequality for angles 120°

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, probability, bells-inequality

In 1964, John Bell first derived the original Bell inequality, $|E(a,b)-E(a,c)|\leq1+E(b,c)$.  Here $a,b,c$ are three different possible spin measurement directions, and $E$ is the measured correlation, meaning the expectation value of the product of the signs of the two outcomes, given the specified measurement settings. (For example : there are two detectors A and B, and spin is measured in units of $\hbar/2$,now if for a particular measurement A measures +1 and B measures -1 then their product is -1, if we consider many runs of the experiment and caculate the average of the product for directions $a$ and $b$ which is $P(a,b)$, then quantum mechanics predict $P(a,b)= -a.b$.)

From this form of Bell's inequality, consider starting with a singlet spin state, and defining these three measurement directions such that the angle between each of the vectors of spin measurements are 120°. Then, I find that the correlations are $E(a,b)=-a.b= 1/2=E(a,c)=E(b,c)$. Thus $|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}|\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}$ means $0\leq3/2$ which satisfies Bell's inequality, instead of violating it.

And yet this example is [often used](https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-bells-theorem-proved-spooky-action-at-a-distance-is-real-20210720/) to show a violation of Bell's inequality.  In the linked article, the calculation agrees with mine, showing that for any two different measurements, the outcomes have the same sign 75% of the time and a different sign 25% of the time.  So the correlation functions $E(a,b)$, etc., are all indeed 0.5.  Please help explain in what way this system violates the Bell inequality.

Comment: Of interest: this question is a general discussion of cases where the inequality is not violated: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732247/

Comment: @TobiasFünke:  See Mermin's ["Bringing home the atomic world: Quantum mysteries for anyone"](http://hep.ucsb.edu/courses/ph125_02/mermin.pdf) (1981), which considers entangled photons encountering a pair of detectors having with three settings 120° apart.  This illustration of Bell's inequality was later picked up by other authors, including (off the top of my head) Moore in *Six Ideas that Shaped Physics* and Maudlin's *Quantum Nonlocality and Relativity*.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Preskill in his lecture notes http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph229/ also uses that Bell inequality (which afaik is the original one by Bell) to explain this. (Chapter 4.2)

Comment: @SubhajitPodder This is pure guessing (partly for the reasons explained above), but: In the standard Bell inequality, the measurements must be in *opposite* directions for the two parties. It is hard to tell since you don't explain your formulas, but *could* it be that in that case, there is an additional minus sign, so that P = -1/2 instead of 1/2, which would violate the inequality?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch and Mauricio The OP took the equation |E(a,b)−E(a,c)|≤1+E(b,c) directly from Bell, see https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/bell/Bell_On_EPR.pdf formula [15].  Note that P(a,b) et al has been exchanged to E(a,b) et al, so the OP uses both interchangeably.  Basically, Bell is saying that the quantum expectation values E() should match the probability P() of a viable (local) realistic theory.  So I think Subhajit Podder has actually been reasonably clear in this.  Obviously the reference would have cleared this up much earlier.

Comment: @DrChinese The OP only ever used P. (In fact, checking the edits, only a minor fraction of the post is by the OP, so it is *really* hard to say what they think.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer, already given in a comment, isn't that there is a factor of two in the angles; rather, it's the fact that the quanta magazine used a different inequality than the one originally formulated by Bell. More specifically, they used an inequality [due to Mermin](http://olivernash.org/2020/11/01/bell-inequalities-mermin/mermin-1981.pdf), which you can also read more about [here](http://olivernash.org/2020/11/01/bell-inequalities-mermin/index.html).

In Mermin's scenario, we have three random variables for Alice and Bob each: $A_j$, $B_k$, and $j,k = 1,2,3$. These variables correspond to the different settings for Alice and Bob, and take on the values $\pm 1$. We are interested in how often Alice and Bob give the same answer, which is given by the product of their random variables. The sum of these products is lower bounded:

$$
\left|\sum_{jk}A_jB_k\right| \geq 1
$$

since there are nine terms in the sum, and the smallest value is when four (five) are +1 (-1) or vice versa. Let's look at the case where

$$
\sum_{jk}A_jB_k \leq -1.
$$

Let the joint expectation values be $E(A_j,B_k) = E(A_j B_k)$. Then

$$
E(\sum_{jk}A_jB_k) = \sum_{j}E(A_j,B_j) + \sum_{j\neq k} E(A_j,B_k) \leq -1.
$$

If we require anti-correlated outcomes when Alice and Bob choose the same setting ($E(A_j,B_j) = -1$) this can be written

$$
\sum_{j\neq k} E(A_j,B_k) \leq 2
$$

If you do the same for the other sign in the absolute value you get $\sum_{j\neq k} E(A_j,B_k) \geq 4$.
Taking the settings $A_i = B_i = \{0^{\circ},120^{\circ},240^{\circ}\}$ we see that the quantum prediction violates the inequality

$$
4 \nleq \sum_{j\neq k} E(A_j,B_k) = 6\cdot\frac{1}{2} = 3 \nleq 2.
$$

If you want to write the inequality on a form even more similar to the original Bell inequality you can use $E(a,b) = E(b,a)$ (this follows from the requirement of anti-correlation for same settings) to simplify it to

$$
E(a,b) + E(a,c) + E(b,c) \leq 1 \ \text{or}\ 
2\leq E(a,b) + E(a,c) + E(b,c) \\
\iff
|E(a,b) + E(a,c) + E(b,c) - \frac{3}{2}| \geq \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Note that neither this form of the inequality, nor Bell's original one, are experimentally testable since they use perfect anti-correlation for equal settings as part of the derivation.

**Edit:** I actually don't think the bound $E(a,b) + E(a,c) + E(b,c) \geq 2$ is necessary. It's easy to show that there is a strategy that satisfies $E(a,b) + E(a,c) + E(b,c) = 1$, and if there was one that satisfied $E(a,b) + E(a,c) + E(b,c) = 2$ a convex combination of them could violate the inequality. Maybe someone can show this in a more direct way.

Comment: Right, that's precisely the version of the inequality (and the storyline provided, cf. your second link) by Preskill in his lecture notes, Sec. 4.2!

Comment: ... Your last inequality looks strange. I mean ... it says 2<=1.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch thanks, that was a stupid way to write what I meant.

Comment: I think the curly bracket is still confusing: What you mean is "or", what at least I would implicitly think is "and".

Comment: How can that quantity be smaller than 1 and larger than 2 at the same time?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch indeed, it should be "or". However like I added, I think only one of the inequalities is needed anyway, because probabilistically picking strategies outside the excluded interval would give a strategy with an expectation value that lies inside the interval, and this isn't possible. For this inequality it's easy to simply enumerate all possible assignment of hidden variables and see that they are always on one side of the interval (this is what they do in the quanta magazine article).

Comment: Fully agree with all you say, except that 2<=1 ;)

Answer (score 5):

Bell's inequality is not necessarily violated for *all* possible angles between measurement directions - it may be that measurements at some angles meet Bell's inequality, as in the example you have given.

However, we know that Bell's inequality is violated for *some* angles between measurements. A common example is when the measurements are at $0$, $45$ and $90$ degrees - see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).

Your confusion may arise from the fact that some explanations of Bell's theorem use a set up of detectors in which $P(a,b) = \cos^2 (\frac {\theta} 2)$; this set up is different from that in Bell's original paper, where $P(a,b) = - \cos \theta$.

Comment: The standard Bell inequality *is* violated for the 120-degree alignment. There seems to be an error in the OPs calculation (or definitions), which needs to be clarified.

Comment: yes, but I remember that  for 120 angles it should be violated , also see https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-bells-theorem-proved-spooky-action-at-a-distance-is-real-20210720/

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Can you show the calculation which demonstrates that Bell's inequality is violated when the detectors are set an angles $0, 120, 240$ degrees, so $P(a,b) = P(a,c) = P(b,c) = - \cos 120^o = \frac 1 2$ ?

Comment: The OP claims that it *is* violated in this setting, and indeed, this is precisely what is usually said. The subtlety is that Alice's and Bob's axes have to be aligned the *opposite* direction, and I think this is precisely the OPs confusion.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch No, no, no. The OP says that Bell's inequality is *not* violated in the $0,120,240$ case and they think it should be. But their calculation is correct - the inequality is *not* violated in the $0,120,240$ degrees case, but it does not need to be because Bell's theorem does not say the inequality is violated for *all* possible settings of the detectors, but only for *some* of them.

Comment: Of course that's what Bell's theorem says (well, in fact it does not say that: It only says that this inequality is not violated for LHV models). Of course, for it to be non-trivial one should give one state where it is violated. Now the OP clearly says " And yet this example is often used to show a violation of Bell's inequality. ", so they think that this state should violate Bell's inequality. Whether it does depends how this inequality is defined, and from the question, this is certainly not clear. There is certainly *one* version of the inequality which is violated by that state ...

Comment: ... (see e.g. Preskill's lecture notes, Chapter 4, where he derives a Bell inequality -- afaik the one from the original paper -- and precisely shows that it is violated by the 120-measurement (with *opposite* meas. directions for A and B) on a singlet state.)

Comment: In keeping with several of the comments above: a) For a=0 degrees; b=45; c=90 you have |-.707 - 0| <=1+ -.707 which is then .707<=.293 and the Bell inequality IS violated. Or b)  For a=0; b=120; c=240 you have |.5 - .5|<=1+ .5 which is 0<=1.5 and the inequality is NOT violated (agreeing with OP).  Note that the b) angle settings are instead usually used for *photon* entanglement rather than *electron* entanglement, which does lead to a violation of an associated inequality.  I believe the quantamagazine reference makes a technical error in their calculation of the QM expectation value.

Comment: Is this on photons or electrons? The angle might differ between the two...

Comment: @Mauricio see my comment above. Indeed the violations occur at different angles for electrons vs. photons.  The 120/120/120 case is not violated for electron spin, but is violated for photon polarization.

Answer (score 2):

This experiment you describe can indeed be used to show that something non-classical is going on.  However, as you noticed, you can't see that non-classicality by looking at Bell's original inequality from his 1964 paper.  (Note that this is an inequality which is barely used anymore; these days the gold standard is the [CHSH inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality).)  True, unlike CHSH, that original inequality had three settings, as does your example.  But the non-classicality of your example isn't apparent until you also analyze the additional three (perfect) anti-correlations $E(a,a)=-1$, $E(b,b)=-1$ and $E(c,c)=-1$.  With these perfect anti-correlations in the mix, you can indeed show that there is no classical account of these experiments.

If you're asking about the relevant inequality which these correlations violate, the [original point of this very example](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/49/10/940/1051474/Bringing-home-the-atomic-world-Quantum-mysteries) was to avoid that sort of technical argument.  Instead, Mermin wanted to show that the assumptions behind Bell's original Inequality (and the CHSH, and others) must be violated without using inequalities.  The argument simply shows that there is no classical explanation for the experiment.  In other words, given the [usual assumptions behind Bell's Theorem](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.92.021002), there is simply no set of hidden states which will allow both the correlations you calculated as well as the perfect anti-correlations $E=-1$ for the same settings.

**EDIT:**  The wrong paper was cited before; this set-up was from Mermin, and indeed the experiment has its own [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%27s_device).